# PHP Google API delete event

Tags: php, symfony, events, google-calendar-api

I'm deleting an google calendar event. Everything seems to be ok, I'm getting http code 204 but the event is still in the calendar. Are there something like types or range of deleting events (documentation is realy poor) in this API?

For authorization I use refresh token - if it matters.

```
public function deleteEvent()
{
    try {
        $service  = new \Google_Service_Calendar($this->initGoogleClient($user));

        $result = $service->events->delete($googleCalendarId, $googleEventId, ['sendNotifications' => true]);
        dump($result);

        return $googleEventId;

    } catch (\Google_Service_Exception $ex) {

        return $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Here is my initGoogleClient function

```
public function initGoogleClient($user)
{
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey("");
    $client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfigFile('C:\client_secret.json');
    $client->setClientId("-.apps.googleusercontent.com");
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
        $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$this->router->generate('google-api-calendar'));
    }
    $refreshToken = $user->getGoogleCalendarRefreshToken();
    if($refreshToken) {
        $client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
    }

    return $client;
}
```

It seems to depend on that:

> - If the user is the organizer of the event, the event will be deleted    from the calendars of all the guests.
> - If the user is a guest on the    event, the event will only be removed from the calendar of the guest.
> - If the owner of the event is deleted, executing the request will not    run successfully and will return an error. You'll need to
>     remove the    event from each of the guest's calendar individually.

When organizer is my API (I think)

```
 "organizer" => array:3 [▼
      "email" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com"
      "displayName" => "gp-test-1-6310b"
      "self" => true
    ]
```

End here is creator

```
"creator" => array:1 [▼
      "email" => "account@gmail.com"
    ]
```

There are no guests

Here is all the data

```
Google_Service_Calendar_Event {#692 ▼
  #collection_key: "recurrence"
  +anyoneCanAddSelf: null
  #attachmentsType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttachment"
  #attachmentsDataType: "array"
  #attendeesType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee"
  #attendeesDataType: "array"
  +attendeesOmitted: null
  +colorId: null
  +created: "2016-12-16T22:26:19.000Z"
  #creatorType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator"
  #creatorDataType: ""
  +description: "Pokój o numerze: 10"
  #endType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime"
  #endDataType: ""
  +endTimeUnspecified: null
  +etag: ""2963854359645000""
  #extendedPropertiesType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties"
  #extendedPropertiesDataType: ""
  #gadgetType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventGadget"
  #gadgetDataType: ""
  +guestsCanInviteOthers: null
  +guestsCanModify: null
  +guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: null
  +hangoutLink: null
  +htmlLink: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=Y29kYjZwcjU5ZWE0bG5hNnMwdDNsYmZiOTAgZWFxOGY1OXZxaW5zOTc3b2h2MXI0dDBlZ2tAZw"
  +iCalUID: "codb6pr59ea4lna6s0t3lbfb90@google.com"
  +id: "codb6pr59ea4lna6s0t3lbfb90"
  +kind: "calendar#event"
  +location: "Kawdawwaws"
  +locked: null
  #organizerType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventOrganizer"
  #organizerDataType: ""
  #originalStartTimeType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime"
  #originalStartTimeDataType: ""
  +privateCopy: null
  +recurrence: null
  +recurringEventId: null
  #remindersType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders"
  #remindersDataType: ""
  +sequence: 0
  #sourceType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventSource"
  #sourceDataType: ""
  #startType: "Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime"
  #startDataType: ""
  +status: "confirmed"
  +summary: "Zarezerwowany Pokój: 10"
  +transparency: null
  +updated: "2016-12-16T22:26:19.864Z"
  +visibility: null
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: array:5 [▶]
  #processed: []
}
```

## anotherupdate

When I try to run this command on this site

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete
(right sidebar, Try this API) event is deleted successfuly. Now i need to know the diference between auth on the site and my google init function.

Any ideas?

Comment: now I dont have idea what else to do, so any tips would be great too

Comment: Ok, i have done it. I debugged everything and everywhere, but didnt look at my controller where after delete action there was create action, I was literally adding the same event after delete :D and the event had not even the same id - i should check that in first place.